# Can ag search sub-directories with the same name, within a bunch of directories?

Tags: ack, ag

Given a directory structure such as:

```
dev/project1/assets/**
dev/project2/assets/**
dev/project3/assets/**
```

Is it possible to search, from within the dev directory all assets directories only. Given that the project directories will include other sub-directories. I don't want to have to explicitly name each project directory. But something like search on `/*/*/assets`. So x directories deep, with a given name.

Comment: What's wrong with using a glob e.g. from `dev` run `ag pattern */assets` ?